# Sklearn Error, array with 4 dim. Estimator <=2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I been trying import data from yahoo finance via panda then convert it to arrays via .as_matrix(), then as i input the data into the classifer to train, it gives me an error.

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

This below is my code:

```
from sklearn import tree
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

df = web.DataReader('goog', 'yahoo', start='2012-5-1', end='2016-5-20')

close_price = df[['Close']]

ma_50 = (pd.rolling_mean(close_price, window=50))
ma_100 = (pd.rolling_mean(close_price, window=100))
ma_200 = (pd.rolling_mean(close_price, window=200))

#adding buys and sell based on the values
df['B/S']= (df['Close'].diff() < 0).astype(int)
close_buy = df[['Close']+['B/S']]
closing = df[['Close']].as_matrix()
buy_sell = df[['B/S']]


close_buy = pd.DataFrame.dropna(close_buy, 0, 'any')
ma_50 = pd.DataFrame.dropna(ma_50, 0, 'any')
ma_100 = pd.DataFrame.dropna(ma_100, 0, 'any')
ma_200 = pd.DataFrame.dropna(ma_200, 0, 'any')

close_buy = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()
ma_50 = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()
ma_100 = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()
ma_200 = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()
buy_sell = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix

print(ma_100)
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
x = [[close_buy,ma_50,ma_100,ma_200]]
y = [buy_sell]

clf.fit(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple of bugs/things needing fixing.

1. Missing parantheses `buy_sell = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix`
2. `[[close_buy,ma_50,ma_100,ma_200]]` is what gives you your 4 dimensions.  Instead, I'd use `np.concatenate` which takes a list of arrays and appends them to each other either length wise or width wise.  the parameter `axis=1` specifies width wise.  What this does is make `x` an 822 x 28 matrix of 822 observations of 28 features.  If this isn't what you were going for, then clearly I didn't hit the mark.  But those dimensions line up with your `y`.

Instead:

```
from sklearn import tree
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

df = web.DataReader('goog', 'yahoo', start='2012-5-1', end='2016-5-20')

close_price = df[['Close']]

ma_50 = (pd.rolling_mean(close_price, window=50))
ma_100 = (pd.rolling_mean(close_price, window=100))
ma_200 = (pd.rolling_mean(close_price, window=200))

#adding buys and sell based on the values
df['B/S']= (df['Close'].diff() < 0).astype(int)
close_buy = df[['Close']+['B/S']]
closing = df[['Close']].as_matrix()
buy_sell = df[['B/S']]


close_buy = pd.DataFrame.dropna(close_buy, 0, 'any')
ma_50 = pd.DataFrame.dropna(ma_50, 0, 'any')
ma_100 = pd.DataFrame.dropna(ma_100, 0, 'any')
ma_200 = pd.DataFrame.dropna(ma_200, 0, 'any')

close_buy = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()
ma_50 = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()
ma_100 = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()
ma_200 = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()
buy_sell = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()  # Fixed

print(ma_100)
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
x = np.concatenate([close_buy,ma_50,ma_100,ma_200], axis=1)  # Fixed
y = buy_sell  # Brackets not necessary... I don't think

clf.fit(x,y)
```

This ran for me:

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            random_state=None, splitter='best')
```

Comment: what does np.concatenate do

Comment: So when this runs, will it be, the price, ma_50,ma_100,ma_200. Will those data be fed into the clf as one

Comment: the first 7 columns of x are identical to `close_buy`.  The next 7 are identical to `ma_50' and so on.  So... yes.

Comment: The underlying arrays, `close_buy`, `ma_50` and such are already `np.arrays`.  It seemed a natural fit.  The answer is yes, it's possible but it would be cumbersome and are you sure you want that?

Comment: i gives me another error, which is ValueError: Unknown label type: array([[  7.87401353e+02,   7.93261381e+02,   7.87071324e+02, ...,
          5.48000000e+06,   3.96049623e+02,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  7.95991368e+02,   8.07001373e+02,   7.95281379e+02, ...,
          5.88550000e+06,   4.03022676e+02,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  8.05301357e+02,   8.08971379e+02,   7.91791350e+02, ...,
          5.54900000e+06,   3.95834832e+02,   1.00000000e+00],

Comment: I just re-verified the code I have posted.  It still works for me.  What versions of sklearn `import sklearn; sklearn.__version__` are you using?  I have 0.16.1.

Comment: the latest version from anoconda