# 3d Array error in Sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multidimensional-array, dataframe, scikit-learn

So im trying to get data about the stocks, the close price and moving averages 50, 100, 200. I got an another array which then is the label which is buy or sell. It was worked out on a dataframe along with all the other arrays. But the problem is when i try to train the classifer, it gives me an error:

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

`When I concatenate the array, it gives me an error, ValueError: Unknown label type: array([[7.87401353,]])` with more values in it
This is my code:

```
from sklearn import tree
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np

df = web.DataReader('goog', 'yahoo', start='2012-5-1', end='2016-5-20')

close_price = df[['Close']]

ma_50 = (pd.rolling_mean(close_price, window=50))
ma_100 = (pd.rolling_mean(close_price, window=100))
ma_200 = (pd.rolling_mean(close_price, window=200))

#adding buys and sell based on the values
df['B/S']= (df['Close'].diff() < 0).astype(int)
close_buy = df[['Close']+['B/S']]
closing = df[['Close']].as_matrix()
buy_sell = df[['B/S']]


close_buy = pd.DataFrame.dropna(close_buy, 0, 'any')
ma_50 = pd.DataFrame.dropna(ma_50, 0, 'any')
ma_100 = pd.DataFrame.dropna(ma_100, 0, 'any')
ma_200 = pd.DataFrame.dropna(ma_200, 0, 'any')

close_buy = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()
ma_50 = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()
ma_100 = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()
ma_200 = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()
buy_sell = (df.loc['2013-02-15':'2016-05-21']).as_matrix()  # Fixed

list(close_buy)

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
X = list([close_buy,ma_50,ma_100,ma_200]) 
y = [buy_sell]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sklearn Error, array with 4 dim. Estimator <=2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361116/sklearn-error-array-with-4-dim-estimator-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a variable `X` that is a list of 2-d arrays.  That automatically implies a 3rd dimension.

```
# offending line
X = list([close_buy,ma_50,ma_100,ma_200])
```

This needs to be concatenated to maintain 2 dimensions.

```
# corrected
X = np.concatenate([close_buy,ma_50,ma_100,ma_200], axis=1)
```

Also, I suspect that once this problem is fixed you'll have another with:

```
 y = [buy_sell]
```

There is no reason to wrap this in `[]`.  This will cause the same 3 dimensional problem.  Just put this:

```
y = buy_sell
```

Comment: I get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Samuel/PycharmProjects/untitled3/777.py", line 41, in <module>
    clf.fit(x,y)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 177, in fit
    check_classification_targets(y)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 173, in check_classification_targets
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y)
ValueError: Unknown label type: array([[  7.87401353e+02,   7.93261381e+02,   7.87071324e+02,]    
      
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: things worked out, apparently i need a Regressor not a classifer